# Normalizing Sales Database for sales amounts

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, normalization

Right now, there is a Sales database which contains sales product detail columns as well as the sales amounts together in one table.

For example:
ProductID, ProductName, Jan14...Dec14, Jan15...Dec15

The issue right now is that there are too many columns right now since we keep on adding 12 columns every year to accommodate the sales amount data. We are trying to separate this table into 2 tables, one for the product information, and one for the sales amount data based on period. Any ideas on how the sales amounts table should be structured?

We are collection amounts on a monthly basis,so what should be the period identifier for the sales amounts table?
Should it be '201501' for jan 2015 or should we have 2 separate columns for month and year for every sales.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, congratulations on deciding to normalize your data.

This is a very simple question with a very simple answer.   You just need two tables:

> Product Table (ProductID, ProductName)
>
> ProductSales Table (ProductID, SalesPeriod, SalesAmount)

`ProductID` and `ProductName` are nothing new.  In the `SalesPeriod` column you would store the periods you are summarizing Sales Totals for (2014, 2015 etc, or maybe 2014Q1, 2014Q2 etc, whatever you want to summarize by); and the `SalesAmount` column is the Total Sales for that period.

You'll populate `ProductSales` with one row for every `Product`/`SalesPeriod` combination.

Finally you add a Foreign Key to `ProductSales` that says that `ProductID` references the `ProductID` column in the `Product` Table.

Comment: You might want to represent the SalesPeriod as a valid datetime, such as '01/01/2014' for Jan 2014, and so on.   It could make aggregating and querying the data much easier further down the road.

Comment: so will it better to have a separate primary key for the productsales table?

Comment: we might also want to pivot the table back to the unnormalized version (jan15..dec15) for analyzing, so will datetime as salesperiod be best?

Comment: Depends on whether any other tables need to refer to it.   If not, then making Product & SalesPeriod the PK is fine.  For pivoting purposes, it won't matter whether the SalesPeriod is datetime or string.   But for doing Date Functions, it will be very helpful to use Datetime (example:  Get all months between Date A & Date B)

Answer (score 0):

I think sales amount is calculating data which can be calculated when you need it.

But if calculating takes long time and you using this data often
Separated table for sales amounts can be created

`ProductID (INT PRIMARY KEY)`, FOREIGN KEY from Product information table
`MonthNumber (INT PRIMARY KEY)`,
`YearNumber (INT PRIMARY KEY)`
`Amount (DECIMAL)`

Product information table remain same, except columns for sales periods

`ProductID (INT PRIMARY KEY)`,
`ProductInfo (NVARCHAR)`,
`OtherInfo (NVARCHAR)`

Then every month you just adding new row with amount for every products  '

Period of the amounts can be represents in different ways
Based on your needs: `Month` and `Year` are only values you need to represent a period of sales.
It can be little bid faster querying data without manipulating and take advantage of the indexes
For example if Period will be represented as `DateTime`
then query with `WHERE MONTH(PeriodDate) = 4`  will be executing without using of indexes